# Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I know this has been asked before. I'm checking to see if there are any new clever solutions. Is there a better way to bind the `SelectedIndex` of a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`? This is how I got the binding to work after much Googling:

```
<!-- This is a little ridiculous -->
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Batch Type"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource methodOfPaymentItemsProvider}}">

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" 
                    Value="{Binding MethodOfPayment, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" 
                    Value="{Binding MethodOfPayment, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer for binding SelectedIndex,ItemSource, IsReadOnly of a DataGridComboBoxColumn.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Batch Type"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource methodOfPaymentItemsProvider}}">

  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding MethodOfPayment,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Streets, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
 </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding MethodOfPayment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Streets, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
     </Style>
 </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
 </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```